# How to find .babelrc?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I want to create React app with [Ant Design](https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started)

In the docs, it says I need to change .babelrc to modularly load the files, also from https://medium.com/@GeoffMiller/how-to-customize-ant-design-with-react-webpack-the-missing-guide-c6430f2db10f..

But, I can't find any.. I'm very new to Webpack/Babel/other things...
I used create-react-app to make React app

Please help..

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ant",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.6.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "less": "^2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "less-vars-to-js": "^1.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

for anyone that ends up here in the future, some clarification: when you create your project with CRA, the babel configuration exists as part of the react-scripts setup (react-scripts is the package responsible for all the tooling magic of CRA). this means all babel related controls are nested somewhere inside of your project's `node_modules` directory. for all intents and purposes, they are not editable, and ejecting is required.

Comment: There is now a command for this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject

Comment: Pls explain how to do bable configuration after ejecting.

Answer (score 12):

If you have created React app using create-react-app, first you need to eject from the app so that you can use custom configuration. Check this official doc about custom setup : [link](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#converting-to-a-custom-setup)

Note: this is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back!

Once you run "npm run eject" when you are in a react app, you can then use custom babel presets. After ejecting from project, go to package.json and you will find babel presets.

There are two ways to edit your Babel configuration in your react app

1) Edit directly using package.json :

```
{
  "babel": {      // nest config under "babel"
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
    ],
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
  }
}
```

2) Create new .babelrc file and edit the configuration :

```
    //.babelrc
     {
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Comment: so, I can just edit the babel configuration in the package.json directly without creating .babelrc?

Comment: Yes, or you can also add .babelrc file in your app root if you don't want to use the configuration in package.json

Comment: Without ejecting, is the `.babelrc` existing ? If yes, do you know where ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa
You can find configuration under `node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/create.js`

Github: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-react-app/create.js

Comment: @coderakki  i was looking for this from long, can you tell me about webpack what it is ?