# PrismJS babel config not working in React

Tags: reactjs, prismjs

I have babel-plugin-prismjs installed,
made .babelrc with this code:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        ["prismjs", {
            "languages": ["javascript", "css", "html"],
            "plugins": ["line-numbers", "show-language", "copy-to-clipboard", "toolbar", "inline-color"],
            "theme": "prism-tomorrow",
            "css": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

and imported Prism to App.js.

This is the code in App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Prism from "prismjs";

const code = `
const foo = 'foo';
const bar = 'bar';
console.log(foo + bar);
`.trim()

function App() {
  useEffect(() =>{
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }, [])

  return (
    <pre className="line-numbers">
      <code className="language-js">
        {code}
      </code>
    </pre>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But the webpage is not highlighting the syntax. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this in a react project built from `create-react-app` (CRA), your code will not work. Your .babelrc file is not being used. CRA does not expose babel configuration. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966285/how-to-find-babelrc) to understand more on this.

For your use-case the easiest way would be to [go to prismjs page to download the CSS file](https://prismjs.com/download.html#themes=prism-okaidia&languages=markup+css+clike+javascript). Select the right theme and click 'DOWNLOAD CSS' at the bottom of the page.

Import this CSS file in your App.js code.

```
import '../prism.css';
```

This will work for Javascript and some other built-in language packs. If proper markup for your language doesn't show up you will need to import those languages manually as well.

Note: This is just a work around to not ejecting your CRA project. The recommended way is still to use babel-plugin-prismjs if you can.